# BeautifulSoup Close all unclosed image tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Python Beautiful soup to find all the images in a folder of html files and then close any img tags so that the emails can be placed in a system that only supports XHTML.

Currently I have:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(engage, "html.parser")
images = soup.find_all('img')
print(email_name + ": " + str(len(images)) + " images were found.")
soup.prettify()
```

This does work and will pull all of the images in my emails then outputs them with the email name and how many images were found. However this also targets already closed images. I'd like it to find only images like.

```
<img src="..." alt="...">
```

and have it ignore any images that are already closed

```
<img src="..." alt="..."/>
```

Then go and close all the others. Finally then check to make sure none were missed.

I was working on regex before moving to BeautifulSoup and made this for finding only closed images.

```
(<img[^>]+)(?<!/)/>
```

But i'm not sure how I can make this work with BeautifulSoup or even if there is a more BS way of doing the same thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup find_all can take a regex like this:

```
import re
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("your regex here")):
    print(tag.name)
```

More info on this you can find here [BeautifulSoup regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)
Another way to search image tags is native regex:

```
for tag in re.findall(re.compile('<img\b[^>]*[^/]>'), str(soup)):
    print( tag)
```

Finally
`<img\b[^>]*[^/]>` - this part of regex must give you an idea on how to get non closed img tags
More on regex and [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html?highlight=re%20compile#re.compile) you can find here